# mifare classic AuthenticateKeyNo() getting a error "Reference key not useable"

Tags: c#-4.0, mifare

I'm using a mifare classic 4k card. I try to write text in the second block of the card. When I try the function `AuthenticateKeyNo(1, 1, MifareKeyType.KT_KEY_A)`, it gives me the following error:

> "Reference key not useable"

This is my code:

```
public void WriteData()
    {
       IReaderUnit reader = null;
       var readerProvider = new PCSCReaderProvider();

       IEnumerable readerList = readerProvider.GetReaderList();
       IEnumerable found = (IEnumerable)readerProvider.WaitForReaders(new string[] { "SCM Microsystems Inc. SCL010 Contactless Reader 0" }, 1, true);
       foreach (IReaderUnit item in found.OfType<IReaderUnit>())
            reader = item;

            if (reader.WaitInsertion(30000))
               {
                 if (reader.Connect())
                   {
                      chip chip = reader.GetSingleChip();
                      if (chip is MifareChip)
                       {
                         IMifareCommands cmd = chip.Commands as IMifareCommands;

                         MifareKey key = new MifareKey();
                         key.Value = "ff ff ff ff ff ff";

                         cmd.LoadKeyNo(1, key, MifareKeyType.KT_KEY_A);
                         cmd.AuthenticateKeyNo(1, 1, MifareKeyType.KT_KEY_A);
                         cmd.WriteBinary(1, "test");
                       }

                   }
               }
     }
```

I use *liblogicalaccess.com dll*

Can anybody explain me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue, because you are providing `String` value as a Key. Keys are ussually `Byte-arrays` (0xFF, 0xFF,..).

In the GitHub project of the Library you used, I could see in the example they used `fromString("FF FF .. FF")`  so fromString might be converting the `String` into something else (probably byte-array or Hex values).

Comment: Thank you for reply but it did not solved the error @DavidK

Comment: Hello igotlib, are you sure you have BLANK, company fresh, MIFARE Classic? As FF is the default key only if noone else changed it before to something else.

Comment: Yes i'm sure. but are you sure that the error means that i use a  wrong key?

Comment: I've got such feeling. Why they key otherwise wouldn't be usable? It seems that something's wrong with the key itself, but message sounds as if Classic is locked. If you have any chance to develop in Java or Android I would suggest using TapLinx - a dedicated library for MIFARE and NXP NFC products on higher level (no APDUs).

Answer (score 0):

can you read block 3 of your card? By transport configuration you should really use key A for login, but it is also possible that by access bits combination you should login with KeyB only, not KeyA, like **MifareKeyType.KT_KEY_B**. Or, if you would post block 3 data - it would be really easier. Also, check pls under debug which bytes you send exactly. So, for "FFFFFFFFFFFF" it should be like: 255 255 255 255 255 255